# How to get bound column value in VBA -MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a `combo box` in my `form` which I filled from another table `role`.
`role` has two columns : `Id` and `Role`
Given my table in `Row Source` and `Bound Column` value as 2 and `column widths` as `0cm;2cm`

I can see my `Role` in combo box which is fine. What I need is

1. On `Submit`, I want to read the `Id` value in `VBA` for the `Role` selected. How to achieve this **-- Resolved it by setting Bound Column value as 1**
2. How to set Default Value as one of the `Role` **-- Help to make this happen**

I have to set similar case for my `ListBox` in same form

Comment: First point is solved now. How to set one of my Role value as Defaulted one when Form loads

Comment: Combobox has DefaultValue property. Put whatever ID you want in there.

Comment: @June7 Thank you. sorry SO not allowing your comment to tick as answer..bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a **multi-column** combo box, both questions relate to the same combobox property : [column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192660.aspx)

```
MyComboBox.Column(Index, Row)
```

Row is optional.

> Use 0 to refer to the first column, 1 to refer to the second column,
>   and so on. Use 0 to refer to the first row, 1 to refer to the second
>   row, and so on.

**Question 1:** Suppose you bound your id to the second column. In the submit code, you can retrieve your id like this: `myid =  MyComboBox.Column(1)`

**Question 2:** Suppose you want to assign `role id = 3` and your id is bound to column 2. In the `Load` event of your form, do this : `MyComboBox.Column(1) = 3`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. I implemented June7 suggestion as it involved no code.

Comment: @VinoM at least you know how to do it if you want to revert back your ID to second column ;-)